# Read links from excel or text file and display them in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, excel, iframe

Hoping there is a solution for this out there. What I'm looking to do is pull data, specifically links, from an excel spread sheet or txt file and display that link in an iFrame. I also need to have a next and prev button that goes to the next cell or line when clicked.

Comment: Embed a web browser activex into your sheet

Comment: Question is a little unclear as it stands.  What environment are you working in - for example where is this iFrame to be displayed, do you have a server and are you extracting excel file info there, or are you trying to do this on the client? And, more importantly, what have you tried (post code if possible) and what happened (post error messages if possible).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'd love to use a google sheet if possible so anyone can update. The idea is to have a left and right arrow in a fixed div on the left and the iframe displaying the webpage on the right. Clicking left or right would go to the next cell and display the next or previous link in an iFrame. The purpose is for quality control of ads running on our YouTube page...one we have all the links entered we can just click left and right to quickly see if ads are running on our videos. I've managed to pull data from a google doc using php but can't figure out the rest.